# InvalidCastException was unhandled by usercode

Tags: c#

when i try this

```
protected void Grid_ViewSorting(Object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
{
        DataGrid myGrid = (DataGrid) sender;
        DataTable datatable =(DataTable) myGrid.DataSource;        
       DataView dataView = datatable.DefaultView;

       if(e.SortDirection.ToString() == "ASC")
       {
                   dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + "DESC";
        } else
        {
            dataView.Sort = e.SortExpression + "ASC";
       }
 }
```

i got the error msg invalidCastException Was Unhandled By userCode
Unable to cast Object OF type 'System.Web.UI.WebControls.GridView' to type 'System.Web.UI.Web.Contro.DataGrid'.

Comment: You are trying to cast GridView to DataGrid :O ? Maybe change your casting

Comment: read the error message, look at the line it says, try something, then come back.

Comment: you can also test for a specific type `if(sender is DataGrid)` before attempting the cast.

Comment: Or even use "as" keyword and check if resulting object is not null :) Just remember to use proper casting

Answer (score 6):

The problem is exactly what the exception says

```
DataGrid myGrid = (DataGrid) sender;
```

The `sender` in this case is of type `GridView` but you're trying to cast it to `DataGrid`.  This is illegal and the CLR hence throws an exception.  You need to account for `sender` being of the type `GridView` and handle it accordingly.

```
GridView myGrid = (GridView) sender;
```